# Problema al hacer un registro en la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, he subido todos los archivos a un servidor gratis, están echas las bases de datos, los archivos lo he probado sin problema via local con *wamserver*,pero ya subidos presenta este problema al insertar datos.

> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u136011330/public_html/insertarweb/registro.php on line 10
>       Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u136011330/public_html/insertarweb/registro.php on line 18
>       Error. Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pagina oficial de PHP expresa:

> Advertencia:  Esta extensión fue obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0, y se eliminó
>   en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar, debe utilizarse la extensión MySQLi o
>   PDO_MySQL...

Te anexo el enlace para mayor detalle http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

como vez es posible que la versión de PHP en el hospedaje que estas usando se este refiriendo a este problema en particular.

Dado que no sea el caso, puede que la solución se encuentre ya publicado en la comunidad STACK EXCHANGE https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448467/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock, donde la respuesta mas aceptada expresa:

> ...cuando se conecta a "localhost" se utiliza el conector de socket, pero cuando se conecta a "127.0.0.1" se utiliza el conector TCP/IP. Puede intentar usar "127.0.0.1" si el conector de socket no está habilitado / funcionando.

Obviamente aplicando la IP correspondiente a su caso en particular.